# Convert Floating Point Number To Integer Via File Read

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I'm trying to get this to work when the "line" is in the format ###.###

Example line of data:

```
Query_time: 188.882
```

Current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    if [ $(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f2) -gt 180 ];
    then
        echo "Over 180"
    else
        echo "Under 180"
    fi
done < test_file
```

Errors I get:

```
./calculate: line 4: [: 180.39934: integer expression expected
```

Comment: I've added the error output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
$ echo Query_time: 188.882 | awk '{ print ($2>180?"Over ":"Under ") 180 }'
Over 180
```

It takes the second space delimited field (`$2`) and using conditional operator outputs if it was over or *under* (less than or equal to) 180.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
line='Query_time: 188.882'
```

This expression:

```
$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f2) -gt 180
```

Will give an error `invalid arithmetic operator` since BASH cannot handle floating point numbers.

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F ':[ \t]*' '{print ($2 > 180 ? "above" : "under")}' <<< "$line"
above
```

Comment: I guess there really was no need for that `int` I was using. Or that `-F`. It really is 7:30sh AM over here...